# How to use suggestion or pop up to suggest while entering text input in kivy?

Tags: popup, kivy, warnings, limit, textinput

Is it possible to use small pop up message or any suggestion to user that while entering please enter numbers between 40-70. I have designed a sample code in which I want user to enter only values between some range. So can someone please help me out so that I can know whether we can do it or not. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MDTextField` widget from the material design inspired kivy library `kivy-md`. This widget has the attribute `helper_text`, which you can set to “Please enter numbers between 0 and 70”. You can additionally set an `input_filter: “int”` to only allow integer values for this widget. Remember that you still haveto validate the values to be in the desired interval. Below is an example of it.

```
MDTextField:
        hint_text: "Helper text on focus"
        helper_text: "This will disappear when you click off"
        helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
        input_filter: “int”
```

Comment: how should I use this method should I just replace TextInput to MDTextField